# iOS UIButton text not getting truncated

Tags: ios, ipad, uibutton, uistoryboard, truncate

I am making an app that generates a UITableView from data. I have a custom UITableViewCell that contains a UIButton with text. The title of one of the generated buttons is too long for the UIButton, but isn't getting truncated as I have selected in the UIStoryBoard. The cells are getting created in my UITableViewController function
`- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath` as normal for prototype cells.

I can't add images because I'm a new user, but here are a couple links to images:

UIStoryBoard Settings: [truncate setting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rHjoN.png)

The title bleeding outside the boundaries of the UIButton: [overflowing text](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ikVzP.png)

Does anyone know how to fix this. It was working earlier. I changed the size of the UIButton and the font of the title text, but I don't think that should make a difference.

Here's the code where I'm setting button's text inside `- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath`

```
    CellIdentifier = @"PopoverCell";
    cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    ((MSPopoverCell *)cell).nameLabel.text = data.FullName; //setting the label, works fine
    [((MSPopoverCell *)cell).button setTitle:data.DisplayString forState:UIControlStateNormal];//setting the button title, bleeds over
```

Also, I'm new to stackoverflow, so if I have missed anything that I should include, please give me some friendly advice.
Thanks,
Max

Comment: I also tried setting the UIButton's LineBreakMode to NSLineBreakByTruncatingTail programmatically with no luck.

Comment: Weird. Setting the text alignment to left fixes the bleeding over, but that's not what I want...

Comment: can you edit your question to show the code of how you're setting the title of that cell's button text?